# insert into database from json if id exists

Tags: c#, json, stored-procedures, serialization, deserialization

I have a json data i read from external files. Sometimes json already has a specific id, sometimes not.

I want to add this json data into **sql server** database, based on those id's. If id exists, do not create a new one, use existing one (from json)...if it doesn't exist, create a new id. (guid)

When i run my code, i get error **insert is not a valid number** error.

**This is my stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Book_Insert
    @book NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @id uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    --if id exists from json (backend code)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Book] WHERE Id = @id)
    BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO [Book] (Id, [Title], Author)
        SELECT Id, [Title], Author
            FROM OPENJSON(@book)
            WITH (Id uniqueidentifier,
                [Title] nvarchar(255),
                Author nvarchar (255))
    END
    ELSE
    --if id doesn't exist yet
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @book_Id char(36)
        DECLARE @pkTable TABLE (NewPK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

        INSERT INTO [Book] (Title], Author) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @pkTable
        SELECT [Title], Author
            FROM OPENJSON(@book)
            WITH ([Title] nvarchar(255),
                Author nvarchar (255),)
            SET @book_Id = (SELECT * FROM @pkTable)
            SELECT @book_Id as ID;
        END
END
```

**My code for adding data**

```
public Task<Book> InsertBook(Book book)
        {
            return _dbManager.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Book>("Book_Insert", new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                { "@book", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book, jsonSerializerSettings)},
                { "@id", book.Id},

            });
        }
```

**fake list with some random data**

```
public List<Book> listOfBooks()
    {

        var bookList = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "Song of ice and fire",
                Author = "unknown"
            }
        };
        return bookList;
    }
```

**add control**

```
Book _book = new Book();
_book = await _bookInterface.InsertBook(new Book()
                {
                    Id = _b.Id, //id exists here
                    Title = _b.Title,
                    Author = _b.Author,
                });
```

**in this case, _b is looped value (foreach book)**

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, but i definitely need help.

Might be something wrong with procedure, maybe this is not even a good way to check if id from backend (json file) exists..i don't really know, i'm not that good with SQL yet.

Any help is appreciated!

**PS - i'm not posting JSON serializing and deserializing methods as when i debug them they work just fine**

Comment: first of all, you missed a comma in the insert statement: INSERT INTO [Book] (Id, Title, Author)

Comment: also here, i think your sql is not well formatted: INSERT INTO (Book, Title, Author) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @pkTable

Comment: it's just a typo when translating frome one language to english @alaa_sayegh

Comment: can you describe, what your stored procedure shall do? if the id is not found??

Comment: insert same data, but create new guid @alaa_sayegh

Comment: i don't know why you are doing it with a stored procedure. I would do it directly in code, easier, neater and you can better control the errors/exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself. Basically very simple. Instead of checking if id exists in database (which after a minute of thinking was quite obvious it does not yet), you check if id exists in @openjson(book). Hope this helps anyone in future.

```
DECLARE
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    SELECT @id =Id 
    FROM OPENJSON(@book) 
        WITH (Id uniqueidentifier)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code in which you check if the id exists, here in your loop

```
Book _book = new Book();
_book = await _bookInterface.InsertBook(new Book()
                {
                    Id = _b.Id, //id exists here
                    Title = _b.Title,
                    Author = _b.Author,
                });
```

And if it exists then you create a new guid.

And insert should be very simple. you write your insert statement and just call execute sql statement, or you can still insert through a stored procedure and you pass your parameters exactly as you are doing now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Book_Insert
    @title NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @author NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @id uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN    
        INSERT INTO dbo.[Book] (Id, Title, Author) values (@id, @title, @author)
END
```

As i mentioned, you can add error handling in your code to catch the exceptions and return proper error messages back.

Hope this helps

Comment: you literally copied my code and basically didn't add anything. the point is this basic procedure of mine, it always enters new guid, no matter what, which means i cannot use it on what im trying to achieve above because it will try to overwrite it. i'm also using my procedure in many different areas, which means it is easier for me to chance procedure once, than changing code in all other areas

Comment: yes i copied your code and did only 2 small changes in the stored procedure, i didn't say that your code is wrong, i just suggested you to do it in this way. Handle the id check in the code and if it exists, create a new one and then call the insert stored procedure. You don't need to change your current SP, you can add a new SP with the code i wrote above. It is just a suggestion dear :)!

Comment: i wasn't trying to be offensive or anything, my bad. i appreciate any input, but i don't think yours is not what i'm looking for...hopefully it will help anyone else tho! thanks again